# How to pick specific cell elements in VTK

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, vtk

For a program I'm writing, I want to be able to pick specific faces of the 3 dimensional object. I can render 3D unstructured data using python wrapper. To make things simpler, suppose I've an unstructured data like this

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
tiny, Created by Gmsh
ASCII
DATASET UNSTRUCTURED_GRID
POINTS 4 double
0 0 0
1.0 0 0
0 1.0 0
0 0 2.0

CELLS 4 16
3 0 1 2
3 0 1 3
3 0 2 3
3 1 2 3

CELL_TYPES 4  
5 
5
5
5
```

I want to interactively pick one or more faces of this 3D object, and get the face, and face coordinates. Note that the 3D object would be rotated, moved. I'm not talking about getting the coordinates of the mouse click. I'm interested in getting "original" co-ordinates or "point ID" of the faces so to speak. 
I'm using python vtk wrapper. Though there is one example on picking and modifying properties (like color), I couldn't find any pointers as to how to extract the picked face (face id/points id) of the 3D object.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `vtkCellPicker` class, especially 
`vtkIdType GetCellId()`.

Documentation: https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCellPicker.html

See this example for usage: https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/Picking/CellPicking/

Comment: Glad it helped. Yes, there is a whole family of picker classes to suit your needs. On vtkCellPicker you can set vtkCellLocator if performance is an issue (e.g. large datasets).